# How to loop through the weeks in a date range with vba

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, vbscript

I have seen how to loop through weeks of a year, w1301,w1302,w1303, I can get the week number if i loop through + on week number but I believe there is a way to directly loop weekly with vba, i hope at least.

```
   DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now)) To DateSerial(2013, 3, 1)

    StartDate = #1/1/2013#
    EndDate = #12/31/2013#

  For DateLooper = StartDate To EndDate
```

I got the function for a week number from date

```
     Public Function IsoWeekNumber(d1 As Date) As Integer
     Attributed to Daniel Maher
     Dim d2 As Long
     d2 = DateSerial(Year(d1 - WeekDay(d1 - 1) + 4), 1, 3)
     IsoWeekNumber = Int((d1 - d2 + WeekDay(d2) + 5) / 7)
     End Function
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: this is looping through days, Is there a neat way to loop through weeks instead of doing it with a +7 on days and getWeek ? apparaently vba can loop by day, maybe it can loop by week too

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by looping through weeks. You can loop from 1 to 52 (`for i = 1 to 52: do something: next i`). You can loop through a date representing the first (or a particular) day of each week. You could find the first day of the first week, then loop through offsetting by 7 days each time, e.g: `For startOfWeek = DateSerial(2013, 1, 1) To DateSerial(2013, 1, 1) + 52 * 7 Step 7` etc. There is no data type representing a week. So either you need to define it as a number (i.e. week number) or as a date type representing a given day of the week.

Comment: Exactly which language are you really interested in?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the [DateAdd function](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview14.aspx?AssetId=HV080007558&lcid=3081&NS=EXCEL.DEV&Version=14&tl=2&queryid=&respos=1&HelpID=vblr6.chm1013094)

```
For i = 1 To 52  
    Debug.Print DateAdd("ww", i, Now())  
Next i
```

Comment: am doing it like this but it only increase for the first iteration      For weekd = #1/1/2013# To #8/28/2013#
    x = DateAdd("dd", 7, CStr(weekd))
    Next weekd

Comment: Just highlighting that there are functions built into vba that will do what you want.  :-)  Though not sure why you would be seeing only the first increase.

Answer (score 0):

A day has an integer value of 1, so you could iterate by week like this:

```
startDate = #1/1/2013#
endDate   = #12/31/2013#

For d = startDate To endDate Step 7
  'do stuff
Next
```

The week number can be determined with the [`DatePart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kt42529%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function, e.g.:

```
WScript.Echo DatePart("ww", Now)
```

This will work in both [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript) and [vba](/questions/tagged/vba).

Comment: i was pretty tired last night and my brain didnt work, this morning i solved it like the answer am posting now, thanks ! btw would step 7 take into considerations the 30,31 days months etc ? and does mine do ?

Comment: @user2708115 When was the last time you encountered a week that did not have exactly 7 days?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution and it seems to work, am not 100% sure of how it handles the 28,30,31 days of different months but i trust vba. i know am making a mistake probably :))

```
  currentDate = "2013-01-02"    ' coz i wanted to start on a wednesday
  for week = 1 to 52
  debug.print currentDate
  currentDate = DateAdd("ww",1,currentDate)
  next week
```

Comment: I think the date is stored as a serial number where each day is an integer, adding 7 or using the dateadd procedure should simply add 7 to that number. The procedure that formats that number into a form that we would recognise will deal with the number of days in each month.

Comment: so in my case am not having anything like that, am just using the currentDate, how to deal with the days in each month ?

Comment: I think that the date you see is just the date number formatted in a special way. If you use `ldate = clng(currentDate)`   `ldate = ldate + 7`
  `currentdate = ldate` it will do the same thing (where ldate is a long variable)