# Proper case text within a range

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to proper case a range and replace the existing text with the first letter of each word capitalized for consistent formatting in our database.
After some research, I noticed `StrConv` can be used with `vbProperCase` although I'm not sure I understand quite how it works:

```
Dim cityNames As Range

Set cityNames = Columns("A:B")

format.Value = StrConv(cityNames.Value, vbProperCase)
```

Comment: You will need to loop the cells, `StrConv` requires a single String and not an array as input.

Comment: Thanks. How can I do this?

Comment: Many examples of looping on here, have a look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18498885/4961700

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PROPER() worksheet function

```
Sub tester()
    Dim ws
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With Application.Intersect(ws.Range("A:B"), ws.UsedRange)
        .Value = .Parent.Evaluate("=PROPER(" & .Address & ")")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: 20 years programming Excel, and never have I thought of using Worksheet.Evaluate in this manner. Respect.

Comment: It's a little clunky but can be much shorter than an equivalent VBA approach.